# Error Code: 1066. Not unique table/alias: 'File'

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL and I'm trying join columns from two ohter table and execute this query

i'm trying arrange the columns like this

- Transaction.TransactionID
- Transaction.TransactionDate
- Transaction.Amount
- TransactionDescription.Description
- File.StartDate
- File.EndDate
- File.FileName

```
SELECT Transaction.TransactionID, Transaction.TransactionDate, 
    Transaction.Amount, TransactionDescription.Description, 
    File.StartDate, File.EndDate, File.Filename
FROM Transaction
INNER JOIN TransactionDescription ON  TransactionDescription.Description = TransactionDescription.Description
INNER JOIN File ON  File.StartDate = File.StartDate
INNER JOIN File ON  File.EndDate = File.EndDate
INNER JOIN File ON  File.Filename = File.Filename
;
```

but when the query is executed i get this error

```
Error Code: 1066. Not unique table/alias: 'File'
```

Why does the error come up?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it?

Comment: on join condition table name should be different for table `file`

Comment: FILE is a KEYWORD !!!!, so its necessary to quote it with BACKTICKS

Comment: @BerndBuffen It's a keyword but not a reserved word. You don't need backticks here.

Comment: @Álvaro González - sorry you 100% right - my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have three `File` tables in your query, MySQL has no way to know which one you mean when you say `File`. You'd normally fix that assigning different table aliases. But it feels rather weird that you actually need to join the same table three times. I have the impression you only want it once, as in:

```
SELECT Transaction.TransactionID, Transaction.TransactionDate, Transaction.Amount, TransactionDescription.Description
,File.StartDate, File.EndDate, File.Filename
FROM Transaction
INNER JOIN TransactionDescription ON  TransactionDescription.Description = TransactionDescription.Description
INNER JOIN File ON  File.StartDate = File.StartDate
    AND File.EndDate = File.EndDate
    AND File.Filename = File.Filename
```